# Invoking Eclipse's export to xml programatically

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to invoke the export to xml function of eclipse programatically to create the build.xml files, so that it can be in a continuous integration process.

Is there an easy way to do it, without opening Eclipse?

Thanks,
Aakash

Comment: What exactly do you want to create build scripts for? E.g. Eclipse plug-ins, web applications, etc.?

Comment: It's a desktop application. So we use the generate ant files to build.

Answer (score 1):

org.eclipse.pde.build contributes an ant task "`eclipse.buildScript`" which generates the build.xml scripts that are using in export and headless pde builds.

There are quite a few properties that serve as inputs to this task.  The simplest way to call it directly from the command line would be something like:

```
eclipse -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -f plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.5.0.v20090521-1730/scripts/genericTargets.xml generateScript
```

You would also need to pass a bunch of -Dproperty=value arguments to set the input properties.  It might be simpler to write a wrapper build.xml script that you would run using the antRunner, in that case, the genericTargets.xml script would be located at `${eclipse.pdebuild.scripts}/genericTargets.xml`.

There is some documentation on the task [here](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_feature_generating_antcommandline.htm).  This is used as part of the larger automated build support provided by pde.build, docs for that start [here](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_feature_build.htm).

Comment: Sorry, due to some unforeseen delay, I was not able to look into this earlier. Now, I am back at the same problem :)

It seems that this task only works for plugins and features, which I don't have. I have a normal Java project, with a .project and a .classpath file. How do I generate the ant file for this project?

Is there a special type and id, in the type@id input to the task?

Thanks
Aakash

Comment: This task generates classpaths according to the MANIFEST.MF.  It doesn't work for normal java projects.  I don't know if there is anything that generates build.xml for regular java projects.  There is an <eclipse.incrementalBuild/> (http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ant_eclipse_tasks.htm) which will run the workspace builder from ant.